# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, array, react, api

Oi! eu criei um site usando Express e React, no express ele recebia uma api externa e enviava corretamente para o react, o problema é que em alguns itens do objeto q era recebido, a aplicação não conseguia manusear, e eu percebi um padrão... por exemplo:

```
const obj = {
 primeiro: 1,
 segundo: [2]
}
```

imagine que obj seja um dado que é recebido pela api(dados criados no próprio react funcionavam perfeitamente), se eu fosse tentar dar um `console.log(obj.segundo[0])` ele me retornaria um erro (isso também vale para protótipos de arrays, porém quando eu executava `Array.isArray()` retornava true). [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu caso quando eu tenho o retorno de `avaLocal.descri.map()` da o seguinte erro
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import load from '../img/home/load.gif'
import web from "../img/icons/website.png"

function Game(){
    const [gameUni, setGameUni] = useState([])
    const [avaLocal, setAvaLocal] = useState([])
    
    //inicio de manuseamento de url
    const URL = window.location.href;
    var args = URL.slice(URL.indexOf("?")+1);
    //var game = window.location.origin + "/games";
    var query = args.split("&");
    var id;
    if(query.length > 1){id = query[0].toString()}else{id = query.toString()}
    id = id.slice(id.indexOf("=")+1)
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            const loadAll = async ()=>{
                try {
                    //api data
                    const promG = await fetch(`/game/${id}`)
                    var listG = await promG.json()
                    setGameUni(listG)
                    
                    //local data
                    const promL = await fetch(`/local/${id}`)
                    var listL = await promL.json()
                    setAvaLocal(listL[0])
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                }
            }
            loadAll();
        },[id])
        //animação de scroll
        window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
            const windowTop = window.scrollY / 100
            if(windowTop > 3) return
            document.getElementById('img-main').style.filter = `blur(${windowTop}px)`
        })
        return(
            <div id="view">
                <h1 id="title-main-uni">{gameUni.name} {gameUni.website && 
                    <div id="website">
                        <a href={gameUni.website} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><img src={web} alt={gameUni.slug} className="websiteLogo" /></a>
                    </div>
                }</h1>
                <div className="local-photo-init">
                    <img src={`${gameUni.background_image}`} alt={gameUni.name} id="img-main" />
                </div>
                
                <div id="content">
                {avaLocal.descri.map((item)=>(<p>{item}</p>))}

                </div>
                {gameUni.length <= 0 &&
                    <div className="loading">
                        <img src={load} alt="loading" />
                    </div>        
                }
                {console.log(gameUni)}
                {console.log(avaLocal)}
            </div>
        )
}
export default Game
```

```
{
 descri: [ "paragrafo1", "paragrafo2", "paragrafo3" ], 
 id: 4354, 
 createdAt: "2021-10-26T17:53:37.269Z", 
 updatedAt: "2021-10-26T17:53:37.269Z" 
}
```

Meus dados Locais do express me retornam isso, sendo que, cada item do array é para ser um parágrafo

Comment: Por favor, evite colocar blocos de código (ou retornos que poderiam estar em blocos de código) como imagens. Para mais informações você pode ler [este post sobre como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485).

Comment: Oi, perdão não sabia que o resultado era importante assim, segue aqui o formato json de restorno padrão de um fetch no local data

{
     descri: [
         "paragrafo1",
         "paragrafo2",
         "paragrafo3"
     ],
     id: 4354,
     createdAt: "2021-10-26T17:53:37.269Z",
     updatedAt: "2021-10-26T17:53:37.269Z"
}

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta para remover as imagens e adicionar esses blocos de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `map()` está tentando ler o `avaLocal.descri`, porém está retornando undefined, pois na primeira tentativa, o `avaLocal.descri` encontra-se sem os dados (undefined), pois ainda não recebeu os dados de sua API. E isso é normal. (Assincronismo e sincronismo)

Uma das soluções é mockar no `useState([{descri: [''}])` já algum dado para o `map()` ler antes de receber os dados da API para que não dê o erro de cara.

Outra solução é validar se os dados foram recebidos. Se sim, fazer o map. Se não, retornar alguma tratativa. Algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde eu inseri o comentário, poderia ser feito o `map()`, pois foi validado que avaLocal.descri não está como `undefined`.

No meu caso a cima, sempre retornará undefined, pois não estou recebendo nada.